# How to make translate event only in shift click

Tags: openlayers-3

is there a way to make ol.interaction.Translate only fires only on shift + click it's really hard to edit a layer when you have Translate and Modify together.

code

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    //toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
    layers: function (layer) {
        return layer.get('id') == 'redline';
    }
});

var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});

var Translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});

map.getInteractions().extend([selectInteraction, modify, Translate]);

selected_features = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate extends `ol.interaction.Pointer`, so [according to the doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Pointer.html), you can provide handler methods for several events. If the handler returns `false`, the even is discarded (at least from the point of view of the Translate).

You also might want to provide a `handleEvent` so that events are not bubbling up to other events in the first place:

> The function may return false to prevent the propagation of the event
>   to other interactions in the map's interactions chain.

so you might want to introduce a global state to keep track if some iteraction is already running and if so, cancel all the other interactions.

```
let isInteractionRunning=false;

const Translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
    handleDownEvent: (evt) => {
        const shiftKeyPressed = evt.originalEvent.shiftKey;

        if (shiftKeyPressed && !isInteractionRunning) {
            isInteractionRunning = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    handleUpEvent: function() {
        // set back global state
        isInteractionRunning = false;
        return true;
    }
});

const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
    handleDownEvent: () => {
        if (!isInteractionRunning) {
            isInteractionRunning = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    handleUpEvent: function() {
        // set back global state
        isInteractionRunning = false;
        return true;
    }
});
```